# Stop watch program in Javascript starting on window load, rather than onclick

Tags: javascript

I am trying to code a javascript stop watch however I am stumped why it begins on window load rather than when the "start" button is clicked. Any help is greatly appreciated, I know there are other errors in the stop and reset functions, but I am starting with this one. I am still new to JS so I apologize if this is super simple. As I understand it onload the onclick functions are set. When the user clicks the "start" button it should call the startStopwatch function. This function call the tickStopwatch every 10ms and updates the stopwatch span's accordingly. I still also have to do the stop and reset functions but clearInterval doesn't seem to be working. Again, any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```js
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };
var evt = {
    attach: function(node, eventName, func) {

    },
    detach: function(node, eventName, func) {

    },
    preventDefault: function(e) {

    }
};

//global stop watch timer variable and elapsed time object
var stopwatchTimer;
var elapsedMinutes = 0;
var elapsedSeconds = 0;
var elapsedMilliseconds = 0;

var displayCurrentTime = function() {
    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getHours();
    var ampm = "AM"; // set default value

    // correct hours and AM/PM value for display
    if (hours > 12) { // convert from military time
        hours = hours - 12;
        ampm = "PM";
    } else { // adjust 12 noon and 12 midnight
        switch (hours) {
            case 12: // noon
                ampm = "PM";
                break;
            case 0:  // midnight
                hours = 12;
                ampm = "AM";
        }
    }
    $("hours").firstChild.nodeValue = hours;
    $("minutes").firstChild.nodeValue = padSingleDigit(now.getMinutes());
    $("seconds").firstChild.nodeValue = padSingleDigit(now.getSeconds());
    $("ampm").firstChild.nodeValue = ampm;
};

var padSingleDigit = function(num) {
 if (num < 10) { return "0" + num; }
 else { return num; }
};

var tickStopwatch = function() {
    // increment milliseconds by 10 milliseconds
    elapsedMilliseconds += 10;
    // if milliseconds total 1000, increment seconds by one and reset milliseconds to zero
    if (elapsedMilliseconds >= 1000) {
        elapsedSeconds += 1;
        elapsedMilliseconds = 0;
    }
    // if seconds total 60, increment minutes by one and reset seconds to zero
    if (elapsedSeconds >= 60) {
        elapsedMinutes += 1;
        elapsedSeconds = 0;
    }
    //display new stopwatch time
    $("s_ms").innerHTML = elapsedMilliseconds;
    $("s_seconds").innerHTML = elapsedSeconds;
    $("s_minutes").innerHTML = elapsedMinutes;
};

var startStopwatch = function(evt) {
    // prevent default action of link
    if (!evt) { evt = window.event; }
    if (evt.preventDefault) { evt.preventDefault(); }
    else { evt.returnFalse = false; }
    // do first tick of stop watch and then set interval timer to tick
    setInterval(tickStopwatch, 10);
    stopwatchTimer = setInterval(tickStopwatch, 10);
    // ??? stop watch every 10 milliseconds. Store timer object in stopwatchTimer 
    // ??? variable so next two functions can stop timer.
};

var stopStopwatch = function(evt) {
    if (!evt) { evt = window.event; }
    if (evt.preventDefault) { evt.preventDefault(); }
    else { evt.returnFalse = false; }
    // prevent default action of link
    clearInterval(stopwatchTimer);
    // stop timer
};

var resetStopwatch = function(evt) {
    // prevent default action of link
    if (!evt) { evt = window.event; }
    if (evt.preventDefault) { evt.preventDefault(); }
    else { evt.returnFalse = false; }
    // stop timer
    clearInterval(stopwatchTimer);
    // reset elapsed variables and clear stopwatch display
    $("s_ms").innerHTML = "000";
    $("s_seconds").innerHTML = "00";
    $("s_minutes").innerHTML = "00";
    elapsedMilliseconds = 0;
    elapsedMinutes = 0;
    elapsedSeconds = 0;

    
};

window.onload = function() {
    // set initial clock display and then set interval timer to display new time every second.
    displayCurrentTime();
    setInterval(displayCurrentTime, 1000);
    // set up stopwatch event handlers
    $("start").onclick = startStopwatch(evt);
    $("stop").onclick = stopStopwatch(evt);
    $("reset").onclick = resetStopwatch(evt);
};
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 450px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 0 2em 1em;
}
h1 {
    color: blue;
}
label {
    float: left;
    width: 11em;
    text-align: right;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
}
input {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
fieldset {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title>Clock</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="clock.css">
    <script src="library_event.js"></script>
    <script src="clock.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <h1>Digital clock with stopwatch</h1>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Clock</legend>
            <span id="hours">&nbsp;</span>:
            <span id="minutes">&nbsp;</span>:
            <span id="seconds">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;
            <span id="ampm">&nbsp;</span>
        </fieldset>
        
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Stop Watch</legend>
        <a href="#" id="start">Start</a>&nbsp;
        <a href="#" id="stop">Stop</a>&nbsp;
        <a href="#" id="reset">Reset</a>&nbsp;
        <span id="s_minutes">00</span>:
        <span id="s_seconds">00</span>:
        <span id="s_ms">000</span>
    </fieldset>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `onclick` needs to be a function. You're calling the function immediately, not returning a function reference.

```
window.onload = function() {
    // set initial clock display and then set interval timer to display new time every second.
    displayCurrentTime();
    setInterval(displayCurrentTime, 1000);
    // set up stopwatch event handlers
    $("start").onclick = function() { startStopwatch(evt);};
    $("stop").onclick = function() { stopStopwatch(evt);};
    $("reset").onclick = function() { resetStopwatch(evt);};
};
```

Comment: Just pass the function, this solution stops the event from being passed to the function directly.

Comment: @Shammoo `evt` is a global variable defined at the top of his code, it's not the Javascript `Event` object.

Answer (score 0):

Age old mistake of calling a function when setting it to the button action, rather than passing the function itself. I've removed the call to the function on `$("start").onclick = startStopwatch;` in the snippets below.

```js
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };
var evt = {
    attach: function(node, eventName, func) {

    },
    detach: function(node, eventName, func) {

    },
    preventDefault: function(e) {

    }
};

//global stop watch timer variable and elapsed time object
var stopwatchTimer;
var elapsedMinutes = 0;
var elapsedSeconds = 0;
var elapsedMilliseconds = 0;

var displayCurrentTime = function() {
    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getHours();
    var ampm = "AM"; // set default value

    // correct hours and AM/PM value for display
    if (hours > 12) { // convert from military time
        hours = hours - 12;
        ampm = "PM";
    } else { // adjust 12 noon and 12 midnight
        switch (hours) {
            case 12: // noon
                ampm = "PM";
                break;
            case 0:  // midnight
                hours = 12;
                ampm = "AM";
        }
    }
    $("hours").firstChild.nodeValue = hours;
    $("minutes").firstChild.nodeValue = padSingleDigit(now.getMinutes());
    $("seconds").firstChild.nodeValue = padSingleDigit(now.getSeconds());
    $("ampm").firstChild.nodeValue = ampm;
};

var padSingleDigit = function(num) {
 if (num < 10) { return "0" + num; }
 else { return num; }
};

var tickStopwatch = function() {
    // increment milliseconds by 10 milliseconds
    elapsedMilliseconds += 10;
    // if milliseconds total 1000, increment seconds by one and reset milliseconds to zero
    if (elapsedMilliseconds >= 1000) {
        elapsedSeconds += 1;
        elapsedMilliseconds = 0;
    }
    // if seconds total 60, increment minutes by one and reset seconds to zero
    if (elapsedSeconds >= 60) {
        elapsedMinutes += 1;
        elapsedSeconds = 0;
    }
    //display new stopwatch time
    $("s_ms").innerHTML = elapsedMilliseconds;
    $("s_seconds").innerHTML = elapsedSeconds;
    $("s_minutes").innerHTML = elapsedMinutes;
};

var startStopwatch = function(evt) {
    // prevent default action of link
    if (!evt) { evt = window.event; }
    if (evt.preventDefault) { evt.preventDefault(); }
    else { evt.returnFalse = false; }
    // do first tick of stop watch and then set interval timer to tick
    setInterval(tickStopwatch, 10);
    stopwatchTimer = setInterval(tickStopwatch, 10);
    // ??? stop watch every 10 milliseconds. Store timer object in stopwatchTimer 
    // ??? variable so next two functions can stop timer.
};

var stopStopwatch = function(evt) {
    if (!evt) { evt = window.event; }
    if (evt.preventDefault) { evt.preventDefault(); }
    else { evt.returnFalse = false; }
    // prevent default action of link
    clearInterval(stopwatchTimer);
    // stop timer
};

var resetStopwatch = function(evt) {
    // prevent default action of link
    if (!evt) { evt = window.event; }
    if (evt.preventDefault) { evt.preventDefault(); }
    else { evt.returnFalse = false; }
    // stop timer
    clearInterval(stopwatchTimer);
    // reset elapsed variables and clear stopwatch display
    $("s_ms").innerHTML = "000";
    $("s_seconds").innerHTML = "00";
    $("s_minutes").innerHTML = "00";
    elapsedMilliseconds = 0;
    elapsedMinutes = 0;
    elapsedSeconds = 0;

    
};

window.onload = function() {
    // set initial clock display and then set interval timer to display new time every second.
    displayCurrentTime();
    setInterval(displayCurrentTime, 1000);
    // set up stopwatch event handlers
    $("start").onclick = startStopwatch;
    $("stop").onclick = stopStopwatch;
    $("reset").onclick = resetStopwatch;
};
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 450px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 0 2em 1em;
}
h1 {
    color: blue;
}
label {
    float: left;
    width: 11em;
    text-align: right;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
}
input {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
fieldset {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title>Clock</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="clock.css">
    <script src="library_event.js"></script>
    <script src="clock.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <h1>Digital clock with stopwatch</h1>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Clock</legend>
            <span id="hours">&nbsp;</span>:
            <span id="minutes">&nbsp;</span>:
            <span id="seconds">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;
            <span id="ampm">&nbsp;</span>
        </fieldset>
        
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Stop Watch</legend>
        <a href="#" id="start">Start</a>&nbsp;
        <a href="#" id="stop">Stop</a>&nbsp;
        <a href="#" id="reset">Reset</a>&nbsp;
        <span id="s_minutes">00</span>:
        <span id="s_seconds">00</span>:
        <span id="s_ms">000</span>
    </fieldset>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```